# Нахождение внутренней точки многоугольника

Tags: алгоритм, вычислительная-геометрия

У меня есть многоугольник заданный множеством своих вершин и мне необходимо найти внутреннюю точку данного многоугольника. Какие алгоритмы существуют для данной задачи? (кроме перебора)

Comment: Если многоугольник выпуклый - да хотя бы среднее арифметическое координат вершин... Если многоугольник может быть произвольный, то сложнее, но можно тупо найти его внутренний треугольник и выбрать точку внутри него...

Comment: Многоугольник может быть любым

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Найдём два различных минимальных значения координаты *y* вершин многоугольника и обозначим их `y'` и `y"`.
2. Возьмём прямую `y = (y" + y')/2`
3. Найдём все точки пересечения этой прямой с многоугольником
4. Найдём два минимальных значения координаты `x` для точек пересечения. Обозначим их `x'` и `x"`
5. Тогда точка с координатами `(x" + x')/2` , `(y" + y')/2` будет являться внутренней точкой многоугольника

Comment: Круто, только по-моему везде - надо заменить на +. Ну и тогда условия < станут не нужны.

Comment: Хмм... - да я миллион случаев найду когда это не выполняется...

Comment: Продемонстрируйте хотя бы один :)

Comment: @Error я не учел замечение @dzhioev (уже поправил ваш ответ) - с учетом этого все верно - это будет внутренней точкой

Answer (score 3):

1. Задаться неким `delta` - ну скажем как 1/100 от длины самой короткой стороны многоугольника
2. Взять любую сторону (лучше всего самую длинную)
3. Взять середину этой стороны и отложить перпендикулярно к ней отрезок длиной `delta` - в обе стороны от нее. Либо одна либо вторая точка на конце этого отрезка будет гарантированно лежать внутри многоугольника
4. Если не получается - берем следующую сторону и повторяем шаг №3
5. Ну если и тут не получается, то берем `delta` и делим на 10 и повторяем шаги 2-4

Answer (score 0):

Есть пример на Turbo Pascal с использованием метода трассировки луча [Проверка на принадлежность точки многоугольнику](http://delphid.dax.ru/www/exampl35.htm)

Comment: Вот только мне не проверка нужна, а именно получить точку (любую), которая лежит внутри многоугольника

Comment: Триангулировать многоугольник -> выбрать произвольный треугольник -> выбрать произвольную точку на выбранном треугольнике.

Answer (score 0):

[Алгоритмы заливки](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116374/), http://algolist.manual.ru/graphics/fill.php - все точки заливки будут внутри многоугольника, берите первую.